# Dependency of the Hessian on the inner product

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, inner-products

**Question**: the gradient of a function $f:E\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, with $E$ being a vector space equipped with an inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$, depends on the choice of the inner product itself. What is the influence of this choice on the Hessian matrix of $f$? In particular, if $E=\mathbb{R}^n$, what is the link between the "regular" Hessian matrix and the one computed with an arbitrary inner product?

**Context**: it seems clear to me how the gradient depends on the choice of inner product: the derivative of $f$ computed at $x$ is a linear function $Df(x):E\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, and so it is an element of the dual space $E^*$. We then have an isomorphism $\Phi:E\rightarrow E^*$ induced by the inner product as $\Phi(x)(y) = \langle x,y\rangle$, which allows us to identify the derivative with the gradient by $\nabla f(x) = \Phi^{-1}(Df(x))$.

I'd like to apply the same reasoning to the second derivative, but I realized I have no clue about where the inner product comes into play. Following the same path, I expect that there is some connection between the second derivative $D^2f(x):E\times E\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ (which shouldn't depend on the inner product) and the derivative of the gradient $D\nabla f(x): E\rightarrow E$ (sorry for the notation!).

**Edit** based on the helpful comment by @NickAlger: what I call $D\nabla f(x)$ can be written as $\Phi^{-1}\circ H_x: E\rightarrow E$, where $H_x$ denotes the Hessian computed at $x$, i.e., the linear operator mapping $E$ to its dual through $(H_xu)(v) = D^2f(x)(u,v)$.

I'm interested in the matrix representation of $(\Phi^{-1}\circ H_x)$ for different choices of the inner product. Since $\Phi$ is always a linear isomorphism, I think this all boils down to taking different bases for domain and image, but I have a hard time formalizing this idea.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The Hessian is conventionally defined as the linear operator mapping the space to the dual space as follows: $E\rightarrow E^*,~~ (Hu)(v):=D^2f(x)(u,v)$. This is what the matrix multiplication $\mathbf{Hu}$ will represent if, for example, you build the matrix in a coordinate system as $\mathbf{H}_{ij}=D^2f(x)(\mathbf{e}_i,\mathbf{e}_j)$. It is also what you need to make the Newton linear system make sense: $Hp=-g$, as the gradient is in the dual space. If you want a mapping $E\rightarrow E$, you can compose the Hessian with the inverse of the Riesz map as $\Phi^{-1} H$

Comment: @NickAlger Thank you, your comment really helps! Then, if I understand correctly, in order to discuss how the eigenvalues change w.r.t. the inner product I need to focus on the matrix of the linear mapping $\Phi^{-1}\circ H$ as we change $\Phi$. Even though I'm still sure on how to attack this..

Comment: @NickAlger Quick follow up: when you write that the Hessian is "conventionally defined" etc., do you have a book/reference that presents it in this way? All the books I checked take the standard inner product for granted, it would really help me to have a more formal introduction!

Comment: Hmm, can’t think of a good reference offhand. This is just what I know from working in optimization for many years. I would say the better way to think about the eigenvalues is through the generalized eigenvalue problem $Hu=\lambda \Phi u$. Of course this is the same up to scaling, but emphasizes that the eigenvectors are orthonormal with respect to the $\Phi$ inner product.